# Prove that a Flagstaff on the top of a tower is off height $d \sin A \sqrt {\frac{2\sin B} {\sin(B-A)}}$

Tags: trigonometry

A flagstaff on the top of a tower is observed to subtend the same angle A at two points distant 2d from each other and lying in a line through the center of the base of the tower in the horizontal plane; and an angle B at a point half way between them. Prove that the height of the flagstaff is $d \sin A \sqrt {\frac{2\sin B} {\sin(B-A)}}$

Can anyone help me??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: a Picture is very helpful

Comment: Sir a picture isn't provided. I'm having a hard time even imagining it. Help me